# How to stop quadprog when Hessian is not symmetric?

Tags: matlab, quadprog

I am trying to solve a quadratic optimization problem using the MATLAB's function quadprog. Actually I am trying to solve many (not one) quadratic optimization problems in series utilizing a for loop, where each qp depends on the results of the previous qp's results. The thing is that sometimes depending on the initial point, the warning: "Your Hessian is not symmetric. Resetting H=(H+H')/2." appears.

**Question 1 & 2:** Does that mean that the solver did not produce a (correct) solution? Or the case is that when the new hessian is used the resulting decision vector can be considered correct, the one that minimizes the objective function?

My (ignorant) idea is that in such case I should stop the simulation and try different initial point. BUT I expected that the exit flag would change from 1 to some other value, and with a simple *if exitflag ~= 1 return end* loop the process would stop. However this is not the case. The exit flag does not change yet the decision variable vector does not seem to be a correct answer.

Comment: Very difficult to answer in general. How do you construct your hessian? You can check if `H == H'` or `max(abs(H - H')) < eps(H)`.